# JavaScript - iterating over a specific nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, nested, key

I've searched high and low for this, but can't find examples similar enough to my own. I have virtually no js experience, so I appreciate any help!

Here is my code snippet:

```
const arr = [];
for (let i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        arr.push({
            name: ["name1","name2","name3"],
            data: [0+i,1+i,2+i],
            })
}
```

This is obviously a very simplified version of my use case, but it should be fine for getting an answer.

For all three [arr]'s that are created, I need to increase each value within arr.data by 1. I have **no idea** how to do this, or if it's even possible.

Edited for sample outputs:

In it's current form, the output will be:

```
Array [
  Object { 
    name: "name1", 
    data: Array [1, 2, 3] 
  }, 
  Object { 
    name: "name2", 
    data: Array [2, 3, 4] 
  }, 
  Object { 
    name: "name3", 
    data: Array [3, 4, 5] 
  }
]
```

I need the arr.data arrays to add 1 (or any other value) to each item in each data sub-array, so the output would be:

```
    Array [
  Object { 
    name: "name1", 
    data: Array [2, 3, 4] 
  }, 
  Object { 
    name: "name2", 
    data: Array [3, 4, 5] 
  }, 
  Object { 
    name: "name3", 
    data: Array [4, 5, 6] 
  }
]
```

I hope that helps. I'm sure I'm using the wrong terminology for this.

Thanks

Comment: Review what "const" does in JavaScript. That may not be appropriate for what you are trying to do.

Comment: @JohnH const does not prevent you from modifying elements within the array. Only from changing the whole array. So it's ok to use it here.

Comment: @Orz Direct it's not clear what you are trying to achieve. Please provide input-output samples.

Comment: I thought I understood the requirements here, but after I posted an answer, I realized that my answer was very similar to your original post before your code was edited, and now I'm not so sure I understand your problem.  I would agree with @yochanansheinberger that it would help to see what you actually expect the array to contain.

Comment: I've edited to include desired output

Comment: That is **definitely not** what the output would be in the current form.  Run the code to prove it, but you are inserting 3 elements in ***every loop***, you would end up with 9 elements.  If you are trying to *update* your elements rather than insert new ones, that can be done, but in that case, the purpose of the loop is a bit of an unknown.  This is feeling a lot more like an XY problem now, since what your examples are showing is something that doesn't require the loop you are trying to use.  What is the ***real world problem*** you are trying to solve?